# How can I deduce that $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}x=1$ without Taylor series or L'Hospital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

How can I calculate this limit without Taylor series and L'Hospital's rule?
$$\lim          _{x\to0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}x=1$$

Comment: It mostly depends on how you define the logarithm.

Comment: See also: [Determine the following limit as x approaches 0: $\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/690898) (Although that question does not have restriction to avoid Taylor and L'H.)

Answer (score 7):

If the limit exists, say $L$, then you can state that:
$$\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\\
\therefore e^L&=e^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}(e^{\ln(1+x)})^\frac{1}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}\\
&=e\\
\therefore L&=1
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 5):

Note [$x \geq \log (1+x)   \geq \frac{x}{1+x} $](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_of_Natural_Logarithm) for all $x > -1$. Since $\frac{x}{x} \to 1$ and $\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. So the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Change the variable and use the continuity of $\ln(x)$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} {\ln(1+x) \over x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} {\ln\left(1+{1 \over n}\right) \over {1\over n} }=\lim_{n \to \infty} n\cdot{\ln\left(1+{1 \over n}\right) }= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left( \ln\left(1+{1 \over n}\right)^n \right) } $$ $$ = \ln\left( \lim_{n \to \infty}{\left( 1+{1 \over n}\right)^n }\right) = \ln(e) = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** :
 It is equal to the caltulation of $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( x+1 \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  } } =e$ just substitute $$t={ \left( x+1 \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }$$