# Solving $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$ without De L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

Trying to solve this limit without derivatives I found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2095162/511355) that is pretty straightforward and I can easily follow the flow. I can understand why ${u\to \infty}$ because:

$$\lim_{u\to\infty}(1 + \frac{1}u)^u = e $$

but how there is a relation to ${x\to 0}$ with ${u\to \infty}$ when we need to find the limit that approaches $0$.

Comment: if $x$ approaches $0^+$, then $u=\dfrac{1}{x}$ approaches $\infty$. Notice that when changing variables you have to change values accordingly.

Comment: I think you should have checked out one answer below. ;) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2097525/331521

Comment: See also: [How can I deduce that $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}x=1$ without Taylor series or L'Hospital's rule?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1598461)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When $u \rightarrow \infty$, $x = \frac 1u \rightarrow 0$, as needed.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Why is this false? As $x$ approaches $0$ (which we want), $1/u$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Don't know why it is downvoted but it answers my question. Will accept when possible.

Comment: $x$ should approach $0^+$ since $u$ goes to $+\infty$(not the downvoter though).

Answer (score 2):

We can squeeze $\ln(1+x)$ between integrals.

- For upper bound we use $\frac 1{1+t}\le \frac 1{1+t_{min}}=1$
- For lower bound $\frac 1t\ge \frac 1{t_{max}}=\frac 1{1+x}$.

$$\dfrac x{1+x}=\int_1^{1+x}\dfrac{\mathop{dt}}{1+x}\le\int_1^{1+x}\dfrac{\mathop{dt}}{t}=\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x\dfrac{\mathop{dt}}{1+t}\le\int_0^x\mathop{dt}=x$$

Now dividing by $x$ we get

$$\dfrac 1{1+x}\le\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}x\le 1$$

Since both sides converge to $1$, this is also the limit for our ratio.

Answer (score 1):

$$A=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$$
Substitute $u=\frac1x$, so the limit becomes $u\to \infty$.
$$A=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left\{u\ln\left(1+\frac1u\right)\right\}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left\{\ln\left(1+\frac1u\right)^u\right\}=\ln\left(\lim_{u\to\infty}\left\{\left(1+\frac1u\right)^u\right\}\right)=\ln(e)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots}{x}=1$$