# Find, from first principle, the derivative of:

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Find, from first principle, the derivative of:
$$\log (ax+b)$$

My Attempt:
$$f(x)=\log (ax+b)$$
$$f(x+\Delta x)=\log (ax+a\Delta x+b)$$
Now,
$$f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\log (ax+a\Delta x+b)-\log(ax+b)}{\Delta x}$$
$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\log (\dfrac {ax+a\Delta x+b}{ax+b})}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: What is first principle?

Comment: What definition do you take for $log(x)$? It is usually defined as $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt$, which would mean the result is straightforward.

Comment: What's the definition of $\log$?

Comment: the result is given by $$\frac{a}{ax+b}$$ if you compute the limit

Comment: @CaveJohnson I think first principle means the limit definition of derivative (if exists). This terminology was used in my secondary school.

Answer (score 9):

From where you left off:

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\log \left(\dfrac {ax+a\Delta x+b}{ax+b}\right)}{\Delta x}$$

$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\log \left(1 +\dfrac {a\Delta x}{ax+b}\right)}{\Delta x}$$

$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\log \left(1 +\dfrac {a\Delta x}{ax+b}\right)}{\Delta x} \cdot \frac{a(ax+b)}{a(ax+b)}$$

$$=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\log \left(1 +\dfrac {a\Delta x}{ax+b}\right)}{\frac{a\Delta x}{ax+b}} \cdot \frac{a}{ax+b}$$

Since:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} (1+h)^{\frac 1h} = e$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \log(1+h)^{\frac 1h} = \log(e)$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log(1+h)}{h}=1$$

Then:
$$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac {\log \left(1 +\dfrac {a\Delta x}{ax+b}\right)}{\frac{a\Delta x}{ax+b}} \cdot \frac{a}{ax+b}$$

$$=1 \cdot \frac{a}{ax+b}$$

$$=\frac{a}{ax+b}$$

Comment: I’m confused: isn’t $\frac{d}{dx}log(ax+b)=\frac{a}{(ax+b)*ln 10}$

Comment: Since the base was not explicitly stated, I am assuming that it is the logarithm to the base of e, however, the answer you provided is correct if the logarithm is instead to the base of 10.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for when someone says 'logarithm' is: Mathematicians mean base $e$, computer folk mean base 2, and engineers mean base 10.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost done! Now, just [recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690898/determine-the-following-limit-as-x-approaches-0-frac-ln1xx): $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} = 1$$

Using this, we get: $$\lim_{\delta x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+\frac{a\Delta x}{ax+b})}{\Delta x} = \frac{\log(1+\color{red}{\frac{a\Delta x}{ax+b})}}{\color{red}{\frac{a\Delta x}{ax+b}}} \times \frac{a}{ax+b} = \frac{a}{ax+b}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the limit $(1+t)^{1/t} \to e$ as $t \to 0$ is known we have
$$(1+at)^{1/t} = \left( (1+at)^{1/(at)} \right)^a \to e^a$$

Therefore,
$$
\dfrac {\log (\dfrac {ax+a\Delta x+b}{ax+b})}{\Delta x}
= \dfrac {\log \left(1+\dfrac {a}{ax+b}\Delta x\right)}{\Delta x} 
= \log \left(1+\dfrac {a}{ax+b}\Delta x\right)^\frac{1}{\Delta x} \\
\to \log e^{\frac {a}{ax+b}}
= \frac {a}{ax+b}
$$