# Prove ${\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty}} \ln{\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)} = \frac{r}{m}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, logarithms

How do you prove ${\lim\limits_{m \to +\infty}} \ln{\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)} = \frac{r}{m}$, where $0 < r < 1$?

I encountered this problem while trying to reproduce the third to last step in this [proof](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~waterman/Teaching/IntroMath99/Class04/Notes/node13.htm).

Comment: How can the changing variable in the limit ($m$) appear outside the limit?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690898/determine-the-following-limit-as-x-approaches-0-frac-ln1xx

Comment: What are the ideas / approaches you have tried?

Comment: I looked at the [link](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~waterman/Teaching/IntroMath99/Class04/Notes/node13.htm) you gave and it says: ''as $m$ gets really large, $\frac{r}{m}$ gets really small, so we can use the log approximation $\ln(1 + h) \approx h$.''

Notice that you can only evaluate a limit of a sum as the sum of the limits if you know the limits exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is *not* the same as the one referred to. It is linked, but here there is clearly a misunderstanding of the notion of limit. So I vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. As $m$ is inside a limit on the left side of your equality, there should be no $m$ on the right side.

What you can say is that $\lim_{m\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac rm)}{\frac rm} = 1$, and you can prove it by studying function $f;x\mapsto \frac{\ln (1+x)-x}{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{m\to+\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right) = \ln(1) = 0$$

$m$ goes to infinity, so the resulting limit can't have $m$ in it.

What's used in the proof is that $\ln(1+h) \sim h$, which is the same as saying $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}{h} = 1$

Answer (score 0):

This formula is meaningless: a limit cannot depend on the dummy variable.

What is meant is probably that both sides are  *equivalent*, denoted
$$ \ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac{r}{m}\Bigr) \sim_{m\to\infty} \frac{r}{m}$$
in the sense that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\smash[t]{\frac{\ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac{r}{m}\Bigr)}{\dfrac{r}{m}}=1}$$
(which does not imply the difference tends to $0$).