# Prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1-e^{-x})^{x} = 1$ without l'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

A bit rusty on my calculus, trying to figure out whether this is correct.

I tried proving $\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} (1-e^{-x})^{x} = 1$ without using L'hôpital.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(1-e^{-x}\right)^{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(1- \frac{x\cdot e^{-x}}{x}\right)^{x}\overset{(1)}{=}\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{e^{-x}\cdot x}=e^{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{x}{e^{x}}}}=e^{0}=1$$

I'm a little unsure about the transition I marked as $(1)$.

Comment: Taking $\log(\cdot)$, it suffices to show $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x \log(1 - e^{-x}) = 0. $$ However, by the L'Hopital's rule, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x \log(1 - e^{-x}) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1 - e^{-x})}{1/x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{-x}/(1-e^{-x})}{-1/x^2} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(-x^2)e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=0.$$

Comment: Please avoid $\rm\LaTeX$ only titles (also @Varun who edited the title).

Comment: @SangchulLee the OP did not want to use H's rule...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for pointing this out to me, I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: @peterag Thank you, I did mean $x \to \infty$, so let me repeat: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac nx \right)^x = e^{-n}$ for a *constant* $n$, but if $n$ depends on $x$ the plot thickens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that as $x \to \infty$

$$\left(1+\frac a{x}\right)^{x} \to e^a$$

is true only for $a\in \mathbb R$ fixed, here we can use that

$$\left(1-\frac1{e^{x}}\right)^{x}=e^{x\log\left(1-\frac1{e^{x}}\right) }=e^{\frac{x}{e^x}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac1{e^{x}}\right)}{\frac1{e^x}} }$$

and use standard limits to get the result indeed

- $\frac{x}{e^x} \to 0$
- $\frac{\log\left(1-\frac1{e^{x}}\right)}{\frac1{e^x}} \to -1$

Refer also to

- [About $\lim \left(1+\frac {x}{n}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358830)
- [How to prove that exponential grows faster than polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55468)
- [Determine the following limit as x approaches 0: $\frac{\ln(1+x)}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/690898)

Comment: Doesn't this mean I need to use l'hopital?

Comment: @ec2604 No we don't need l'Hospital at all. I'll give some reference for that.

Comment: OK. Not quite sure how you get the second limit without l'Hôpital. It's an undetermined form so it seems like the obvious thing to do.

Comment: @ec2604 We have that as $t \to 0$ by standard limit $t\log(1+t)=\log [(1+t)^t] \to \log e=1$

Comment: Or $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1-x)}x=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1-x)-\log(1-0}{-x-0)}$$ and the last expression is a derivative.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes of course, even if often the derivative is proved by the fundamental limit $(1+1/x)^x \to e$.